# Integrate forum software into existing Zend site

Tags: zend-framework, phpbb

I've searched around and haven't really found anything on this, so maybe someone here has tried this before.  My company already has a website built with Zend, and we'd like to add in a forum as well.  All I really need is something that will work with postgresql and has foreign language support (particularly Japanese, but if worst comes to worst, I'll just translate it myself). phpBB fits all my needs though.  Is it possible to get the two working together?  Or is there another forum software that'll work with Zend?  Or is it better to just build the thing from scratch?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of integration are you going for? Does your company website have a login system that you'd want the forum software to be able to pick up on too (i.e single sign-on)?

Comment: That would be very nice, but not absolutely required.  (And actually, I'm trying that out right now, but no success whatsoever so far.) I was asking more generally though, if anyone has done this before and what their recommendations would be.